# How to migrate Files from one SharePoint online site collection to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, document-migration

Scenario: In need to migrate files from one site collection to another.

Any tool or csom code to use.

Note: I am using SharePoint online here

Comment: do you want to migrate filed from on SharePoint site collection to another site collection ?

Comment: @SureshBolineni yes

Answer (score 1):

We can use CSOM code to migrate documents with their version from one site collection to another site collection.

For more information about how to migrate SharePoint document with version using CSOM, you can read below article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakhiguha/2015/12/06/migrate-sharepoint-document-with-version-to-sharepoint-online-using-csom/

In addition, you can also refer to below articles for more information:

http://expert-advice.org/office365/migrate-sharepoint-online-different-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-tenants/

http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-metadata-version-history/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one of the migrator tools to migrate the files from one site collection to another site collection.  here is the link to download one of the tool trail version can be downloaded from here. [Saketa Migrator tool](https://saketa.com/migrator/)

Comment: Is there a cheaper alternative? codes or SharePoint designer workflows

Comment: this is the cheaper and quicker too.. you will just use trail version not paid version of the tool. It won't do any data loss in the migration even in trail version.